# Written html source code in downloaded file from php page

Tags: php, html, web

I have written below code to download a file in a php program:

```
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "GenerateExcel")
{
    $events = Activities::RetDaily($date);

    $file = "../temp/DailyReport.csv";
    header ("Content-Type: application/download");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Length: " . ($fsize));
    readfile($file);
}
```

and I use below script to submit my form:

```
function GenerateExcel()
{
    document.getElementById("Show").value = "<?php echo $showType ?>";
    document.getElementById("action").value= "GenerateExcel";
    document.getElementById("DailyReport").submit();
}
```

when I download the target file, html source code of page is attached to my target file! What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You should `exit()` immediately after `readfile()`

Comment: You should not output a mix of file content and html markup. If you want to transfer a file, then transfer nothing but its content. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: @MikeW Thanks, your soluion solved the problem.